# Indexed based datastructure

Tags: collections, arraylist

I was going throw Java collection information. I encountered the term that ArrayList is the indexed based datat structure. What is the meaning of it? I am confused about it? Is it means that it stores element/object with index.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is part of java collection frame work. Since ArrayLis is an index based data-structure searching or getting element from Array with index is pretty fast. Array provides O(1) performance for get(index) method but remove is costly in ArrayList as you need to rearrange all elements.

For more help on Java collection framework read below book

[Java Collection](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5c_Collection.html)